# Isalpha() function with while loop c++

Tags: c++11

I want to create a `while` loop that will allow me to input a mix of string numbers until I input string that contains all characters.

Also, I have a problem with output

```
int main() {
    string name;
    string temp;
    cout << "Enter your name:";
    cin >> name;
    cout << endl;
    for(auto a:name) {
        if(isalpha(a)) {
            temp=name;
        } else {
            while(!isalpha(a)) {
                cout << "Enter your name without digit:";
                cin >> name;
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << temp << endl;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
for(auto a:name) {
```

This is a loop over the characters in `name`, as entered after the prompt `"Enter your name:"`. The current character is assigned to `a`.

```
    if(isalpha(a)) {
        temp=name;
    }
```

If the letter is alphabetic, assign `temp = name` (*every time* the current letter is alphabetic... this is not what you want!).

```
    else {
```

...if the current character (`a`) is not alphabetic...

```
        while(!isalpha(a)) {
```

...enter a **second** loop, which will loop until `a` is alphabetic...

```
            cout << "Enter your name without digit:";
            cin >> name;
            cout << endl;
        }
```

...**but `a` is never again assigned to.** Your loop does not terminate.

You should re-work your logic. As this looks like a self-study project, I will *not* write the reworked loop for you, as I think you will learn much more from trying to do it on your own.

Comment: A hint on the solution: Your outer loop cannot be over the characters in a given string, as you conditionally want to read in a *new* string (and then loop over *those* characters). You can break out of a loop by `break` or `return`, of which `return` is usually preferred for reasons of code structure. You can also loop as long as a variable is set, and clear it inside the loop once you are satisfied with the input.

Comment: the more important thing is that range for would not react to change of container size and content, it would not reset itself magically to beginning of string. No way range for should be a topmost loop in this scenario. Some overcomplicated for loop could be or I'd used `while`.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: It does not matter if it is range-for, iterator, or index access. Ugly hacks on the loop counter nonwithstanding, you could not (cleanly) reset the outer loop to work on the new string. That is why I said the outer loop could not (cleanly) be the loop over the string contents. -- All that being said, a "proper" solution would *of course* be using [find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead of a loop... and would be checking for absence of `isdigit()` instead of `isalpha()`, as it makes the condition simpler *and* is locale-independent...

Comment: (ctd.) ...as well as working as expected on UTF-8 strings as well as plain ASCII. ;-)

Comment: I think we said same thing in different words, I didn't saw your comment until posted mine.C for() loop encompasses all possible loops with check at beginning of loop, and may not use counter at all , it just one of common uses for it. Actually it is defined as while(). What I meant that uppermost loop must be repeating  input and input correctness check until string check passes. Would not you need  wstring class for Unicode?